# How to convert a Git partial clone into a full clone?

Tags: git

(Note: this question is *not* about shallow clones or sparse checkouts. Partial clones are described here: [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html), [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone).)

**TL;DR:** after making a partial clone (tree-less, not sparse, not shallow) using `git clone --filter=tree:0`, how do I undo the filtering?

---

### Problem

Let's suppose I'm making a tree-less partial clone of a large repository in Git:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/bminor/binutils-gdb.git --filter tree:0                     
Cloning into 'binutils-gdb'...
<...>
```

After running some operations on the repo, I want to convert it into a full clone.

---

### Manual procedure (suggested in GitLab docs)

GitLab docs suggest a procedure which involves some manual plumbing to get the list of missing objects and fetch them manually, then disable filtering: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html#remove-partial-clone-filtering

Running the instruction as published fails because there are some 100k missing objects which is too long to insert on a command line. However, even after working around this it fails:

```
$ git rev-list --objects --all --missing=print | grep -oP '^\?\K\w+' | parallel -m --tty git fetch origin
remote: Enumerating objects: 269, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (265/265), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (249/249), done.
remote: Total 269 (delta 217), reused 16 (delta 16), pack-reused 4
Receiving objects: 100% (269/269), 135.74 KiB | 716.00 KiB/s, done.
remote: Enumerating objects: 4808, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2420/2420), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2020/2020), done.
remote: Total 4808 (delta 1539), reused 400 (delta 400), pack-reused 2388
Receiving objects: 100% (4808/4808), 3.38 MiB | 3.47 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1761/1761), done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (218/218), completed with 14 local objects.
fatal: bad revision '01008c52e3270cd0adc1c845a0f7ff633015da8f'
error: github.com:bminor/binutils-gdb.git did not send all necessary objects
<...>
```

---

### `git fetch --refetch`

I have discovered a `git fetch --refetch` option that looks like it's supposed to do what I want, but I could not find a proper way to use it.

If I disable filtering and then refetch, the automatic `git gc` goes crazy and attempts to unpack all newly-fetched objects, creating ~1M files and taking about half an hour:

```
$ git fetch --no-filter -refetch
OR
$ git config --unset remote.origin.partialclonefilter; git fetch --refetch
remote: Enumerating objects: 1120538, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4672/4672), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1715/1715), done.
remote: Total 1120538 (delta 3129), reused 4397 (delta 2950), pack-reused 1115866
Receiving objects: 100% (1120538/1120538), 649.79 MiB | 6.60 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (919098/919098), done.
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Enumerating objects: 181032, done.
Counting objects: 100% (178515/178515), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (163958/163958), done.
Writing objects: 100% (178515/178515), done.
Total 178515 (delta 15015), reused 163026 (delta 13221), pack-reused 0
<at this point, git pack-objects hangs for 30 minutes doing small file I/O>
```

Alternatively, if I disable filtering, unmark origin as a promisor and then refetch, the subsequent git gc crashes mid-way because of failing to find some objects and leaves the repo in a broken state:

```
$ git config --unset remote.origin.partialclonefilter; git config --unset remote.origin.promisor; git fetch --refetch
remote: Enumerating objects: 1120538, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4672/4672), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1711/1711), done.
remote: Total 1120538 (delta 3130), reused 4400 (delta 2954), pack-reused 1115866
Receiving objects: 100% (1120538/1120538), 650.19 MiB | 6.50 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (919119/919119), done.
Auto packing the repository for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
Enumerating objects: 178515, done.
Counting objects: 100% (178515/178515), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (162147/162147), done.
Writing objects: 100% (178515/178515), done.
Total 178515 (delta 15032), reused 178514 (delta 15032), pack-reused 0
fatal: bad tree object 41aa4766fa1a0629852ad386574b9b8997b3b91e
fatal: failed to run repack
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: maybe --unshallow (not tried)?

Comment: The new `--refetch` option is at least partly intended for fixing a corrupted Git repository. The partial clone de-partial-ing support just isn't really there yet in Git, and you're probably best off just doing a full clone. @OznOg: `--unshallow` won't help here as the repository isn't actually *shallow*, it's just full of "promisor objects".

Comment: I *think* there's also some plan to use `--refetch` and/or smarten up the protocol to help with filling out partial clones, but right now Git tends to fetch one promised object at a time, which is really painfully bad.